# Migration to Polymer 2.0 Hybrid mode

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I woult migrate my app from Polymer 1.9.1 version to Polymer 2.0 version.

Currently I updated the template of components to hybrid mode.

I did such types of changes:

1)replace content tag with slot tag

2)replace ::content with ::slotted

3)wrap styles with template tag

But my hybrid elements still have references to components under polymer 1.9.1.

So when I try to use these hybrid components, I receive error:

```
polymer-micro.html:449 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.
```

When I am replacing references to Polymer 1.9.1 with Polymer 2.0 I am also getting the error.

So, could you please advice, what should I do for running my hybrid component under Polymer 2.0? 
Is it possible to leave the references to Polymer 1.9.1? Or is it not possible to run such components under Polymer 2.0?

Should I do some other actions for migration to Polymer 2.0?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not do this exact thing, but I used to get a very similar error when I had the same element included (at least) twice with different path.. so maybe you should check your imports to make sure they follow the same pattern..

Comment: Thank you Mishu.
Yes, I am checking the imports. Maybe it's the root of issue.
Also looks like there is no possibility to have references to Polymer 1.0 and Polymer 2.0 on the one page. So, all components on the page should be ran under Polymer 2.0.